# Mysql Nginx Proxy with VERIFY_IDENTITY

Tags: mysql, ssl, nginx, rds

We have configured an Nginx proxy for AWS RDS to get a static IP address, which has to be whitelist on the Network ACL outbound of the VPC on another AWS Account ( tunneling is not possible ). The Nginx proxy pass is working but the MySQL server validation ( VERIFY_IDENTITY ) is failing with the error.

> mysql -h Proxy Server Address --ssl-ca=rds-ca-2015-root.pem --ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY  -u admin -p
>
> Failed to verify the server certificate via X509 certificate matching functions

I use this AWS Document to download the CA certificate [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html)

Nginx configuration

```
stream {
   upstream mysql_server {
      server *******.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306;
   }
   server {
      listen                3306;
      proxy_pass            mysql_server;
   }
}
```

I am missing anything on the Nginx configuration or is it not possible to do the server identity verify when the AWS RDS is behind the Nginx TCP proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using `rds-ca-2015-root.pem` and looks like your rds server has been updated to 2019 certificate. you need to download the new certificate and connect again

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/ssl-certificate-rotation-mysql.html

Comment: no, I haven't updated to 2019 certificate, still using the 2015 certificate. Tested can able to connect to the RDS using the endpoint given by AWS with 2015 certificate.